# How to bind the hashmap to thymeleaf radio button using th:field attribute in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, thymeleaf

I want to display the radio button input values ​​on the thymleaf page and save the radio button input values.

However, as you can see below, my model class uses hashmap to get input values(persons) ​​and set input values (persons).

```
private HashMap persons= new HashMap();

public void setPerson(String key, Object value) {
    this.persons.put(key, value);
}

public Object getPerson(String key) {
    return this.persons.get(key);
}
```

In thymleaf page radio button, I need to get the input value from the hashmap for the specific key (person) and also set the input values ​​for the hashmap for the specific key (person) (loading and saving the data)

Basically, I need to bind the specific keys on the persons hashmap with the radio buttons in the thymleaf page.
I tried to used the th: field attribute to bind the key but it did not work

```xml
<input type="radio" th:field="*{persons.get('person1')}" value="0"/>
<th:block condition>
  // input labels for value 0= No
</th:block>

<input type="radio" th:field="*{inputs.get('person1')}" value="1"/> 
<th:block condition>
  // input labels for value 0= yes
</th:block>
```

Also I tried like below. Now it show the input values (works get method in hashmap) but I cannot save the input value (not set the radio button input to the hashmap)

```xml
<input type="radio" value="0" name="persons(person1)" 
       th:checked="*{persons.get('person1')=='0'}"/>
```

Could you guys help me to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking in Thymeleaf is `th:each`. It's construction that you can use to iterate through collections. (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration)

You are looking for solution for `HashMap`:

> Any object implementing java.util.Map. When iterating maps, iter
> variables will be of class java.util.Map.Entry.

So in your example it would be something like this:

```html
<div th:each="entry : ${map}">
    <p th:text="${entry.key}">entry key</p>
    <p th:text="${entry.value}">entry value</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If value will be an object, then you will need another dot and field name.